# Adding USGS WMTS to Mapbox gl js?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, usgs

How do you add a wmts layer from the USGS basemaps found here as a mapbox-gl-js layer?:

https://viewer.nationalmap.gov/services/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I used:

`'https://basemap.nationalmap.gov/arcgis/rest/services/USGSImageryOnly/MapServer/WMTS/tile/1.0.0/USGSImageryOnly/default/GoogleMapsCompatible/{z}/{y}/{x}'`

I found this answer buried in the code here:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/AzureMapsCodeSamples/blob/master/AzureMapsCodeSamples/Tile%20Layers/WMTS%20Tile%20Layer.html